# NVIM fails to initialize in Windows 10

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm attempting to start neovim after installing neovim via chocolatey. I've put the config files in %LOCALAPPDATA% as required (I'm using the Primagen's repository from his GitHub).

Overall directory structure looks like this:

```
C:\USERS\TROMB\APPDATA\LOCAL\NVIM
│   init.lua
│
├───after
│   └───plugin
│           cloak.lua
│           colors.lua
│           fugitive.lua
│           harpoon.lua
│           lsp.lua
│           refactoring.lua
│           telescope.lua
│           treesitter.lua
│           trouble.lua
│           undotree.lua
│           zenmode.lua
│
└───lua
    └───theprimeagen
            init.lua
            packer.lua
            remap.lua
            set.lua
```

I've also installed packer via the following command

git clone https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\packer.nvim"

When I start up nvim, I get the following error

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim/lua/theprimeagen/set.lua:17: attempt to concatenate a nil value
stack traceback:
        C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim/lua/theprimeagen/set.lua:17: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim/lua/theprimeagen/init.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:1: in main chunk
Error detected while processing C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim\after\plugin\cloak.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: C:\Users\tromb\AppData\Local\nvim\after\plugin\cloak.lua:1: module 'cloak' not found:
        no field package.preload['cloak']
        no file '.\cloak.lua'
        no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\cloak.lua'
        no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\lua\cloak\init.lua'
        no file '.\cloak.dll'
        no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\cloak.dll'
        no file 'C:\tools\neovim\nvim-win64\bin\loadall.dll'
```

Of possible consequence is the following output from nvim :help nvim-config:
Configuration                           *nvim-config*

- Use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` instead of `.vimrc` for your |config|.
- Use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` instead of `.vim` to store configuration files.
- Use `$XDG_STATE_HOME/nvim/shada/main.shada` instead of `.viminfo` for persistent
  session information.  |shada|

==============================================================================

Where the configuration specifically doesn't recognize nvim-data in it's config. What gives?

neovim version 0.9.1